# install plugin for Open Distro

Tags: elasticsearch-opendistro

Amazon Elasticsearch Service offers k-Nearest Neighbor (k-NN) search which can enhance search by similarity use cases.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/03/build-k-nearest-neighbor-similarity-search-engine-with-amazon-elasticsearch-service/

I tried this official code that I found here...

https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/k-NN

```
PUT /myindex
{
    "settings" : {
        "index": {
            "knn": true
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "my_vector1": {
                "type": "knn_vector",
                "dimension": 2
            }, 
            "my_vector2": {
                "type": "knn_vector",
                "dimension": 4
            }, 
            "my_vector3": {
                "type": "knn_vector",
                "dimension": 8
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Getting this error:

> "unknown setting [index.knn] please check that any required plugins
>   are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed
>   settings"

How do I check if my Elastic installation supports this feature?

Comment: official forum thread:  https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=319241

Comment: Could  you please check knn.plugin.enabled=true present in the cluster settings or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

t2.small and t2.medium instance types are not supported. (It is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation.) It worked as expected when r5.large instance type was selected.